# Yodlee - Need list of currency codes used for BankData class

Tags: currency, yodlee

Yodlee has a currencyCode property for each property of type "YMoney".  Can anyone supply me with a list of valid currencyCode values Yodlee may return?

In the US, I get "USD" but we want to use this application in various countries.  If I know the list of currency codes used by Yodlee, I could design my database fields appropriately to store this informaiton.

Thanks,
Raney Eden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currencyCode returns the ISO Code of the Currency. So, the list that you can define is all  the valid ISO Currency codes.